# Skip csrf verification in pyrocms

Tags: laravel, pyrocms

I need to skip csrf verification for one of my endpoint. So I add that route to `$except` array in `Anomaly\Streams\Platform\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` like this,

```
protected $except = [ "/payments/notify" ];
```

But still it not skip the csrf verification. So, please help me with this.

Comment: can you share your controller ?

Comment: If you are using laravel framework the default path to `$except` array is `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` .

Comment: @WebMan in pyrocms they have alternative way

Comment: Okay then you should provide more code to help in your situation :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
protected $except = [
     "payments/notify",
     "payments/notify/*"
 ];
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What have you changed and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `api` middleware group:

[image]

Or either you can use the resource controller:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it listed in documentation. This page should get you started (see included links on page for more options too): https://pyrocms.com/documentation/streams-platform/1.6/the-basics/csrf-protection